# How to clear values of a custom field when pushing back button in commerce checkout?

Tags: commerce

In my shop there is a custom pane where the customer can check a checkbox in order to choose "private invoice" (if he checks, the invoice amount will include VAT but will not report it; instead a small discount is given). The Problem: if the customer goes back to the prevoius checkout-page and unchecks the checkbox, this change will not be reflected. How can i make sure, the value is updated propperly?